# Run commands from web application

Tags: web-applications, command-line, terminal, batch-processing, certificate-authority

I am currently trying to run a command on the command line from a web application. Is it possible do from a web application?

The command(on terminal):

```
cd ejbca/bin
./ejbca.sh batch
```

How do I run these in a web application when a button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would make a listener running apart from the web application. And when your button is pressed, just send a message to the listener, and the listener will do it as normal.

For messaging, you may want to use [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Java code

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("myshell.sh");
```

myshell.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ejbca/bin
./ejbca.sh batch &
```

Inside your example.jsp

```
<form method="get">
<input type="submit" name="example" value="Push Me" alt="example button">
<% 
    if ("Push Me".equals(request.getParameter("example"))) {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("myshell.sh");
    }
%>
</form>
```

Comment: Note this is a fairly crude example.  You can capture stdout and stderr in separate threads and drop the ampersand.

Comment: Where should the myshell.sh be created?

Comment: I am trying to do this on a jsp page.
This is what I tried:

<%Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ejbca.sh batch"); %>
 <tr id="Row<%=(row++)%2%>">
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td<input type="button" name="Generate test" value='<c:out value="Generate Test"/>' tabindex="<%=tabindex++%>"
    onClick='proc'> Is this right?

Comment: The script ejbca.sh should be on the $PATH of the user running your servlet container.  This is more easily done outside of your app, for example, in that user's ~/bin folder.  If you're trying to deploy ejbca.sh within your app, you may need to chmod it some executable permissions after it is deployed.

Comment: I don't understand. I have this web application ejbca located in /home/user/ejbca. The file I want to run is in /home/user/ejbca/bin/ejbca.sh  The ejbca web application is running on jboss server. Executing 'ehbca.sh batch' would create a new folder '/home/user/ejbca/p12/pem'and also create a few certs in that folder. A page on the web application would have a button which would run the file and create the folder and file. How would it be possible to execute the file with a press of a button on the web application page?